# EvoPdf.HtmlToPdf isn't rendering foreign languages (Hindi, Bengali)

Tags: c#, html-to-pdf, pdf-conversion, evopdf

I'm using EvoPdf.HtmlToPdf with paid license, however, I have noticed that when I'm converting HTML to PDF and downloading, some languages like Hindi, Bengali are not rendering properly.
Here is the code snippet I'm using.

```
using EvoPdf.HtmlToPdf;

PdfConverter pdfConverter = new PdfConverter();
pdfConverter.LicenseKey = "my_key";

string html = "<html><body><div>This is to test bengali language আমার বাংলা পরীক্ষা করা দরকার</div></body></html>";

byte[] data = pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromHtmlString(html, baseUrl);

ResponseLogic.BinaryWrite(Guid.NewGuid() + ".pdf", data);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

I've been researching evo pdf so much lately I'm sorry I can't track down exactly where I read this.